# Polynomial taking irrationals to irrationals

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, problem-solving, irrational-numbers

**Problem:** Find all polynomials from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ $f$ with integer coefficients taking irrationals to irrationals.

**My attempt:** It is clear that the problem statement is equivalent to finding all $p(x)$ over $\mathbb{Z[x]}$ such that $k+p(x)$ does not have any irrational root for any $k \in \mathbb{Q}$. Stated in another way, $p(x)$ does not cut the x-axis at any irrational point when it is vertically translated by any arbrtitrary rational amount. In particular $p(x)$ cuts the x-axis only at rational points, if it cuts at all.

I dont know what to do next. Someone please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all polynomials that fix $\mathbb Q$ and the irrationals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262410/find-all-polynomials-that-fix-mathbb-q-and-the-irrationals)

Comment: Not a duplicate because it doesn't also stipulate that it fixes $\mathbb{Q}$. This is a similar but different problem.

Comment: Also this problem asks for integer coefficients not complex.

Comment: The result is the same however.  If you have a polynomial of degree $\geq 2$ with integer coefficients, there will be some irrational number which gets mapped to a rational number instead.  This is a specific case of the problem I linked to.  Polynomials of degree zero (constant maps) won't even work in this case due to the constraint of the coefficient needing to be an integer.  The result will be that it must be a polynomial of degree exactly one.  The techniques employed in the linked question still apply.

Comment: It is also easy to reduce the other problem to this case, first noting that it must have rational coefficients because it is its only interpolating polynomial for enough of its rational points, and then multiplying by the denominators of the coefficients.